# Apache Ignite REPLICATED SYNC IgniteCache is not populated upon creation

Tags: java, ignite

I have an Apache Ignite Server node cluster and some `IgniteCache`s defined. The first node in the cluster has populated the cache with some values. When a new node joins, it gets an instance of that cache but when I try to iterate through the existing values the `iterator` has no next element. If I try to access a specific entry via `.get(String key)` then the entry is fetched.

This makes me think that values are not immediately made available to new nodes, even though the replication mode is `REPLICATED` and the rebalance mode is `SYNC`. `SYNC` mode javadoc says that the cache won't start until all necessary data is loaded from other grid nodes which doesn't seem to be the case. I have tried everything from listening to `CACHE_STARTED` events to trying to force a load but nothing works.

I'm just looking to run some logic **after** the `IgniteCache` instance has been created and populated with the grid data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a listener to `EventType.EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STOPPED` and execute any logic inside since this event is triggered after the cache has been populated with its respective data (in this case all of the entries since we have `REPLICATED` mode).

```
ignite.events().enableLocal(EventType.EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STOPPED);
ignite.events().localListen(event -> {
  if(event instanceof CacheRebalancingEvent && ((CacheRebalancingEvent) event).cacheName().equals("myCacheName")) {
    for (Cache.Entry<String, Object> entry : myCache) {
      logic(null, entry.getValue());
    }
    ignite.events().disableLocal(EventType.EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STOPPED);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}, EventType.EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STOPPED);
// ...
IgniteCache myCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration("myCacheName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible cases:

1)You are having rebalance in progress. During rebalance is in progress you will not see some entries on the LOCAL node (via localPeek, eg). But they should be available by normal get/sql (because affinity function will always show the actual location of the key's value. After rebalance this can be changed)

Could you please share your itterator code?

2)New node can be out of baseline (in case of persistence). In this case, such node should be added to the baseline:

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/baseline-topology

Please update you initial question and add cache configuration and code sample. Also provide output of:

```
control.sh --baseline
```

Comment: I found the solution since then. It was the rebalancing issue you mention and when I started listening to `EventType.EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STOPPED` I got the results I was expecting. Wasn't really aware of the rebalancing process until now so this whole thing eluded me.